# Task owner does not change

Tags: data-loader, tasks, owner

When we change owner of a record (Ex opportunity) on Salesforce, there is a message at the top of the page saying :

> This screen allows you to transfer an opportunity from one user to
>   another. When you transfer ownership of an opportunity, the new user
>   will own:
>
> - all notes that were recorded for this opportunity owned by XXXXX
> - all activities (tasks and events) that were recorded for this opportunity owned by XXXXX
>
> Hence, all the activities belonging to the previous owner will be now
>   owned by the new owner.

However, if we change the owner of the opportunity by Data Loader, the activities owner do not change.

Is there a way to change the activities owner while updating the owner of the opportunities by data loader?

Or do we need to update the activities owner separately by dataloader?

Comment: I would guess this is a similar issue when importing data from a system to another. You might have to create a field in the task object to track the new owner, and then run an apex code to set the `OwnerId` to the id stored on said field. Have you tried that?

Comment: The UI for account ownership transfer does work as driven by the various radio buttons presented to the user - as such, you can think of it as a custom service provided to the user by SFDC. Changing the owner explicitly via the API or DataLoader is a DML event that bypasses the aforementioned  "service"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard behavior for transfer of ownership of an Account is to transfer all related Contacts to the new Owner, all open and closed Cases, all open Activities related to the Account, but not closed Activities. Workflow rules that update owners do not also transfer associated items. To ensure transfer of an associated item, you'd want to add them to your dataloader files as well and include workflow to accommodate the owner change of your transfer selections. See this [Help Document](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=account_owner_transfer.htm) for more on the subject.